# Phaser js colliding with world bounds

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Can someone explain where is my mistake in trying to make my player to collide with the bound of the world not just going throw the walls. I tried with custom methods but it is not the effect that I desire.
When I add "game.world.setBounds(0, 0, x, y);" to the create function my game does not start. I am begginer in phaser js so maybe I am doing something wrong. Here is my code:

```js
"use strict";

var game = new Phaser.Game(1000, 800, Phaser.CANVAS, "game_div");

var spaceField,
    backgroundSpeed,
    player,
    cursors,
    bullets,
    bulletsTime = 0,
    fireButton,
    bullet,
    bulletSound;

var mainState = {
    preload: function () {
        //id
        game.load.image("starfield", "images/space.png");
        game.load.image("player", "images/playerSmall.png");
        game.load.image("bullet", "images/fire.png");

        // audio

        game.load.audio("bulletSound", "sounds/blaster.mp3");
    },

    create: function () {
        // Full screen when clicking with the mouse on the screen
        game.scale.fullScreenScaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.EXACT_FIT;
        game.input.onDown.add(goFull, this);
        // background
        spaceField = game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 1000, 800, "starfield");
        backgroundSpeed = 2;
        game.physics.setBoundsToWorld();

        // player spaceship + adding physics + player movement
        player = game.add.sprite(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY + 300, "player");
        game.physics.enable(player, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

        // Fire bullets
        bullets = game.add.group();
        bullets.enableBody = true;
        bullets.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE; // Enabling physics for bullets
        bullets.createMultiple(30, "bullet");
        bullets.setAll("anchor.x", 0.5);
        bullets.setAll("anchor.y", 1);
        bullets.setAll("outOfBoundsKill", true); // Checks if the bullet is off screen so we can reuse it
        bullets.setAll("checkWorldBounds", true);

        fireButton = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR);
        bulletSound = game.add.audio("bulletSound");
    },

    update: function () {
        // Making scrolling background
        spaceField.tilePosition.y += backgroundSpeed;
        player.body.velocity.x = 0; // Everytime when key is not pressed the player does not move
        player.body.velocity.y = 0;

        // Checking which key is pressed

        if (cursors.up.isDown) {
            player.checkWorldBounds = true;
            player.events.onOutOfBounds.add(playerOutOfBoundsTop, this);
            player.body.velocity.y = -350;
        }

        if (cursors.down.isDown) {
            player.checkWorldBounds = true;
            // player.events.onOutOfBounds.add(playerOutOfBoundsBottom, this);
            player.body.velocity.y = 350;
        }

        if (cursors.left.isDown) {
            player.body.velocity.x = -350;
        }

        if (cursors.right.isDown) {
            player.body.velocity.x = 350;
        }

        if (fireButton.isDown) {
            fireBullet();
        }
    }
};

function fireBullet() {
    if (game.time.now > bulletsTime) {
        bullet = bullets.getFirstExists(false);

        if (bullet) {
            bullet.reset(player.x + 28, player.y);
            bullet.bulletAngleOffset = 90;
            bullet.bulletAngleVariance = 30;
            bullet.body.velocity.y = -400;
            bulletsTime = game.time.now + 200;
            bulletSound.play();
        }
    }
}

function playerOutOfBoundsTop(player) {

    //  Move the Spaceship to the top of the screen again
    player.reset(player.x, 60);

}

/*function playerOutOfBoundsBottom(player) {
 // Move the spaceship to the bottom of the screen again
 player.reset(60, player.x);
 }
 */

function goFull() {

    if (game.scale.isFullScreen) {
        game.scale.stopFullScreen();
    } else {
        game.scale.startFullScreen(false);
    }

}
//id
game.state.add('mainState', mainState);

game.state.start("mainState");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want that your player doesn't go out of the game bounds you can just set the property collideWorldBounds to true, in the `create` function:

```
player.body.collideWorldBounds=true;
```

Take a look a [this](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/sprites/collide-world-bounds) phaser example and the [docs](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body.html#collideWorldBounds)

But if you want to do something different when the player is out of bounds you can add a function (like the one you have when the UP key is pressed) in the update loop.

For example, with this code when your player is out of bounds it will appear again in the middle of the game:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(1000, 800, Phaser.CANVAS, "game_div");

var spaceField,
    backgroundSpeed,
    player,
    cursors,
    bullets,
    bulletsTime = 0,
    fireButton,
    bullet,
    bulletSound;

var mainState = {
    preload: function () {
        //id
        game.load.image("starfield", "images/space.png");
        game.load.image("player", "images/playerSmall.png");
        game.load.image("bullet", "images/fire.png");

        // audio

        game.load.audio("bulletSound", "sounds/blaster.mp3");
    },

    create: function () {
        // Full screen when clicking with the mouse on the screen
        game.scale.fullScreenScaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.EXACT_FIT;
        game.input.onDown.add(goFull, this);
        // background
        spaceField = game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 1000, 800, "starfield");
        backgroundSpeed = 2;
        game.physics.setBoundsToWorld();

        // player spaceship + adding physics + player movement
        player = game.add.sprite(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY + 300, "player");
        game.physics.enable(player, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

        //player.body.collideWorldBounds=true;

        // Fire bullets
        bullets = game.add.group();
        bullets.enableBody = true;
        bullets.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE; // Enabling physics for bullets
        bullets.createMultiple(30, "bullet");
        bullets.setAll("anchor.x", 0.5);
        bullets.setAll("anchor.y", 1);
        bullets.setAll("outOfBoundsKill", true); // Checks if the bullet is off screen so we can reuse it
        bullets.setAll("checkWorldBounds", true);

        fireButton = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR);
        bulletSound = game.add.audio("bulletSound");
    },

    update: function () {
        // Making scrolling background
        spaceField.tilePosition.y += backgroundSpeed;
        player.body.velocity.x = 0; // Everytime when key is not pressed the player does not move
        player.body.velocity.y = 0;


        player.events.onOutOfBounds.add(playerOutOfBounds, this);

        // Checking which key is pressed
        if (cursors.up.isDown) {
            player.checkWorldBounds = true;
            player.body.velocity.y = -350;
        }

        if (cursors.down.isDown) {
            player.checkWorldBounds = true;
            // player.events.onOutOfBounds.add(playerOutOfBoundsBottom, this);
            player.body.velocity.y = 350;
        }

        if (cursors.left.isDown) {
            player.body.velocity.x = -350;
        }

        if (cursors.right.isDown) {
            player.body.velocity.x = 350;
        }

        if (fireButton.isDown) {
            fireBullet();
        }
    }
};

function fireBullet() {
    if (game.time.now > bulletsTime) {
        bullet = bullets.getFirstExists(false);

        if (bullet) {
            bullet.reset(player.x + 28, player.y);
            bullet.bulletAngleOffset = 90;
            bullet.bulletAngleVariance = 30;
            bullet.body.velocity.y = -400;
            bulletsTime = game.time.now + 200;
            bulletSound.play();
        }
    }
}

function playerOutOfBounds(player) {

    //  Move the Spaceship to the top of the screen again
    player.reset(player.x, game.world.centerX);
    player.reset(player.y, game.world.centerY);

}

/*function playerOutOfBoundsBottom(player) {
 // Move the spaceship to the bottom of the screen again
 player.reset(60, player.x);
 }
 */

function goFull() {

    if (game.scale.isFullScreen) {
        game.scale.stopFullScreen();
    } else {
        game.scale.startFullScreen(false);
    }

}
//id
game.state.add('mainState', mainState);

game.state.start("mainState");
```

Comment: Thank you the information I was searching about - I don't know how i missed the phaser docs information page : ).